# C++ Optimization breaking OLE Automation program (non-MFC)

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-studio-2013, ole, office-automation

I'm writing a program to parse a Word Document and export data out to an Excel Workbook using OLE Automation (the non-MFC way I guess). Works fine in Debug, not so in Release (specifically if optimization is enabled). The error is that the IDispatch::Invoke call failed, specifically:

`0x80020004 DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND Parameter not found`

I checked StackOverflow for some suggestions and the main one seems to be uninitialized variables. That might be what's going on, but I still don't understand this specific case. I've narrowed it down to a single function in my program `Automation::Dispatch::Invoke` which is responsible for finally calling `IDispatch::Invoke`. The arguments being passed into `Automation::Dispatch::Invoke` are correct so the problem is somewhere in its code.

Looking at the base code (from MSDN) that I adapted this from, I was able to get it working and narrow down the exact problem line. Below shows code that does not work, but the comments indicate the line that I moved to get it working (look for the 2 lines with a `<--- Problem line` comment). In Debug mode, the location of this line does not matter and it works in either spot.

---

My question is what does this fix, and why is it an issue to start with? Thank you and let me know if I can make the question more clear.

---

```css
HRESULT Automation::Dispatch::Invoke(int cmd, std::string name, std::vector<VARIANT> values)
{
  USES_CONVERSION;
  HRESULT result;

  /* Get DISPID for name passed */
  DISPID dispID;
  LPOLESTR nameOle=A2OLE(name.c_str());
  result=pObjectInt->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &nameOle, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispID);
  if (FAILED(result)) {
    return result;
  }
  /* Reverse elements in values vector so they are invoked in the correct order */
  std::reverse(values.begin(), values.end());

  /* Allocate memory for object values */
  VARIANT *pValues=new VARIANT[values.size() + 1];
  for (unsigned int i=0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
    pValues[i]=values[i];
  }
  /* Build DISPPARAMS */
  DISPPARAMS dispParams= {NULL, NULL, 0, 0};
  /* DISPID dispidNamed=DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;   <--- PROBLEM LINE moved here makes it work */
  dispParams.cArgs=values.size();
  dispParams.rgvarg=pValues;

  /* Handle special-case for property-puts */
  if (cmd==DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT) {
    DISPID dispidNamed=DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;   /* <--- PROBLEM LINE here */
    dispParams.cNamedArgs=1;
    dispParams.rgdispidNamedArgs=&dispidNamed;
  }
  /* Make the call */
  if (cmd==DISPATCH_METHOD || cmd==DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT) {
    result=pObjectInt->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, cmd, &dispParams, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  }
  else {
    VariantInit(&objectData);
    result=pObjectInt->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, cmd, &dispParams, &objectData, NULL, NULL);
  }
  delete[] pValues;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Look at the scope of your variable you're **addressing** (`&dispidNamed`) within the block that is broken (stress the *within*). Outside that block *it doesn't exist anymore*. You're thus sending `dispParams` off to an API call nicely loaded with a dangling pointer.

Comment: Oh wow that is pretty obvious... as usual, a huge waste of time on something dumb.

Comment: Truer words of never been spoken of the life of a software engineer. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
if (cmd==DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT) {
    DISPID dispidNamed=DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;   /* <--- PROBLEM LINE here */
    dispParams.cNamedArgs=1;
    dispParams.rgdispidNamedArgs=&dispidNamed;
}
```

`dispidNamed` is a local variable to the code block it is in (i.e. the area delimited by `{` `}`).

After the `}` is reached it ceases to exist. Then `rgdispidNamedArgs` is a dangling pointer because it no longer points to a variable that exists.

You got unlucky in Debug mode that it didn't trigger an error sooner.